# Find the time required for an investment to grow to a given amount with compound interest

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

Find the time required for an investment of 5000 dollars to grow to 7400 dollars at an interest rate of 7.5 percent per year, compounded quarterly. 
Your answer is t=  years.

I got to the point where i have $74000=5093.55^{4t}$ and then I tried putting natural logs in front of both sides of the equation but from there I can't seem to cancel out what I want to to solve for t.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: I have used the compounding interest formula to get the equation 7,400=5,000(1+(.075/4))^4t but then I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: When you obtain the equation $$7400 = 5000\left(1 + \frac{0.075}{4}\right)^{4t}$$ divide by $5000$, then take the logarithm of both sides of the equation so that you can isolate the exponent using the rule $\log x^n = n\log x$.

Comment: Judging by your comment below, it seems like you are having problems understanding how to use logarithms. May I suggest a basic tutorial: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/logarithms.html

Comment: Where did you find a 7.5% investment?

Answer (score 1):

Solve
$$A=P\left( 1+\frac{r}{n} \right)^{(nt)}$$
for $t$ with your values included in the formula.

Recall from properties of logarithms:
$$
\begin{align*}
y=x^k \Rightarrow \log y &= \log x^k \\
&=k\log x.
\end{align*}
$$
Hence
$$k=\frac{\log y}{\log x}.$$

It looks like that exponent rule is where you are getting hung up.

Comment: I get stuck trying to solve for t using logs